# ExportCSV using react-bootstrap-table-2

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to trigger my exportCSV from a different component outside of the `TookkilProvider`... is that possible? I did see some reference to `this.refs.table.handleExportCSV();` [here](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/1104), but I can't seem to find that function

My code is below:

```js
<ToolkitProvider
    keyField="id"
    data={[...data]}
    columns={Columns}
    exportCSV={{ onlyExportFiltered: true, exportAll: false }}
    search
>
    {
        props => (
            <div>
                <MyExportCSV {...props.csvProps} />
                <hr />
                <BootstrapTable keyField='id'
                    {...props.baseProps}
                    pagination={paginationFactory(options)} expandRow={expandRow}
                    ref={n => node = n} />

            </div>
        )
    }
</ToolkitProvider>
```

Comment: If you want trigger `handleExportCSV()` method from a different components, you must throw `BootstrapTable ref` to this components throught props.

Comment: How?  I can't seem to find handleExportCSV() in the node ref, what do I need to pass? I'm not even able to trigger it from the same component, only inside the Toolkit. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Method `handleExportCSV` available only in old version of  `react-bootstrap-table`, in new version you must use `onExport()`. Demo https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Export%20CSV&selectedStory=Custom%20CSV%20Button&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Comment: The link you sent is what I'm doing right now, and I'm calling the export from within the `Toolkit` how do I export the props from the toolkit so i can call it from somewhere else, ref on the table doesn't seem to be it

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, I'm trying to place the export button on another component(parent component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `useRef` in parent and `forwardRef` in child components. Create custom `MyExportCSV` with `hidden input` and pass parent `ref` to it and call `onExport()` on click. Then on parent you can create `button` that will be on click trigger event `click` of child input. I wrote example for you. [DEmo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-feather-be9cd)